# From specific sub-object from object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to remove a specific sub-object from an object in JavaScript.

My object could look like this:

```
{
    "domains": [
        {
            "transfer": "stackoverflow.dk"
        },
        {
            "register": "stackoverflow.no"
        },
        {
            "register": "stackoverflow.name"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is using the filter method in a in the object like this:

```
var remove = selectedDomains.domains.filter(function(e){
    return e === {"register": domain + "." + selectedTLD};
})
```

The domain variable in the function is in this example "stackoverflow" and the selectedTLD is either dk, no or name.

What it does, is remove all of the objects from the object, instead of just one.

What I would like to do is pass in a specific sub-object and remove that from the object.

I hope it makes sense :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two distinct (non-identical) objects are never equal to each other, even if they have the same properties. Just check the `register` property.

```
var remove = selectedDomains.domains.filter(function(e){
  return e.register === domain + "." + selectedTLD;
})
```

`remove` will be an array containing all elements which match the URL.

However, if you want to remove the element from the array, you probably want to change the condition to

```
e.register !== domain + "." + selectedTLD;
```

Comment: Thank you sir! This has been twisting my head for the last 2 hours!